# Why does React fires console.logs 8 times when an event is triggered?

Tags: reactjs, event-handling, rendering

I am new to React and I do not understand why my app render 2 or 8 times.
I am using window.ethereum to interact with MetaMask and have a listener that fires when I change one account in MetaMask. This should fire the console.logs only one time each but they are getting fired 8 times.
If I delete the useEffect they are fired 2 times. No other useEffects in all app.

```
useEffect((loading) => {
    let isMounted = true;
    setDarkMode(JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('isDark')));
    setLoading(true);
    loadBloackchainData(isMounted, loading);
    // cleanup
    return () => (isMounted = false);
  }, []);

  const ethereum = window.ethereum
  ethereum.on('accountsChanged', function (accounts) {
    console.log('is metamask installed?', ethereum.isMetaMask);
    console.log('ethereum.networkVersion : ', ethereum.networkVersion );
    console.log('ethereum.selectedAddress : ', ethereum.selectedAddress );
  });
```

Why are being fired 8 times?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you're inadvertently adding a new `accountsChanged` handler on each render?
Each time you render, you may be adding a new handler, which may be getting called by your app when account info changes.  You should maybe subscribe/unsubscribe from that event within a `useEffect`:

```
useEffect(() => {
  const ethereum = window.ethereum  
  const doAccountThings = (accounts) => {
    // do account stuff
  }
  ethereum.on('accountsChanged', doAccountThings)
  return () => {
    // here unsubscribe from the doAccountThings handler,
    // whatever that syntax is.
  }
}, [])
```

The useEffect docs describe how and why you might need to use this technique to clean up after a subscription: https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-effect.html#example-using-hooks-1